# Can I count my personal projects as experience?

Tags: work-experience

I am currently going to school full time for a BS in Computer Science. In addition to my coursework, I have also been doing my own programming projects outside of class. Could I count this as experience since this is work that I am doing outside of class?

Edit: I am not being paid for this work nor is this work being done for class. This is work that I am doing on my own personal time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am a professional recruitment lead in the one of AI companies.

In my opinion, the projects done in "personal time" along the studies are an added value to your CV - especially if they correspond with the job description you wish to apply for. I think that you can list the projects in the experience section (as the projects actually are your work experience) and below you can add a line stating "Side Projects during the studies" or something similar. Then you can list the projects and information as such: company name/project name if exists,  your role, duration of the project, description of the project, technologies used etc.

However, You need to be careful when writing about certain company - check and keep in mind the clauses in your agreements with the companies you were engaged with. You need to know which information you can place on your CV and which you cannot (ex. company's name, project's name etc.) to avoid potential issues. Also if something is restricted, you need to be carefull in describing this aspect, ex. if the company's name is restricted - you cannot write the description, which can point out immediately the company's name.

Usually side projects during the studies are well received by a recruiter or a hiring manager if presented in a organized and structured way on the CV. It shows that you are a motivated self-starter who is eager to learn and develop.

I hope it helps!

Answer (score 3):

I'm a hiring manager for software folks.  I would not count side projects as "Experience" under the "Experience" section of your resume, but I would look at e.g. a github profile that you put on your resume and consider the kinds of projects and quality of your code (something like a portfolio).